# How to output value of a node that has attribute in XSLT?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I get the value of the element with attribute in XSL?

This is example I am using to test my code.

```html
<CD>
        <a/> <!--N0#1-->
        <b>text</b> <!--NO#2-->
        <c YEAR="value"/> <!--NO#3-->
        <d name="value" ou="aous">9.90</d> <!--NO#4-->
        <e><f>text</f> <!--NO#5-->
            <g>text</g></e>
        <i><h>text</h> <!--NO#6-->
            <h>text</h></i>
</CD>
```

I'd like this NO#4 part to give me output like this:

```
"d" : {
                
                            "@name" : "value",
                         
                           "@ou" : "aous",

                        "VALUE_VARIABLE":"9.90"
                }
```

The problem I am heaving is that i can't get "9.90" element. How can I do this? This is my code:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=last()"> <!--check if current attribute is last-->
                           "@<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="./*"> <!--check if current element has child elements-->
                            "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="(./*) and not(position()=last())">
                            "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            "@<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

EDIT - [here](https://pastebin.com/Z8XS93iS) you can find whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="q">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="nl">&#xa;</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="*[@*]">
  <xsl:value select="name()"/>{
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:if test="position()!=1">,
</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($q, '@', name(), $q, ' : ', $q, ., $q)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($q, 'VALUE_VARIABLE', $q, ' : ', $q, ., $q)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the context of an attribute, you can get the string-value of its parent element using:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".."/>
```

Of course, it is much easier to get it from the context of the parent element itself, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:text>{"d" : {</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:text>"@</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>" : "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>", </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>"VALUE_VARIABLE" : "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"}}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

---

P.S.

```
<xsl:when test="./*">
```

will NEVER be true for an attribute.

---

**Added:**

If you want to make this more generic, try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@*]">
    <xsl:text>{"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>" : {</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:text>"@</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>" : "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="text()">
        <xsl:text>, "VALUE_VARIABLE" : "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am aware that test = "./*" is not passing, that's what I am struggling with. It should be able to work for whatever input that's why i can't use "match=specific_element" template. This select=".." works but I am not sure how can I set conditions in "when" statement. I should check if element with attribute has text, and for each I need to output "VALUE_VARIABLE": "that_value" I am clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: I have added a more generic template to my answer. I am afraid I cannot cover all your possible scenarios, because you only posted a snippet of your code.

Comment: I edited my question, you can find code here: https://pastebin.com/Z8XS93iS Could you take a look, please?

Comment: No, I don't intend to spend that kind of time on this. Believe you have enough here to be able to finish this your own. -- A general advice: generic transformations take a lot of work and rarely fit all possible scenarios.